# SDL2: How to work with monochrome or 16 color surfaces?

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I'm working on a project where I mainly use paletized images with few colors (4bpp). It's not a constraint but I don't need more.

[SDL_PixelFormatEnum](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PixelFormatEnum) defines the following values : `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_INDEX1LSB`, `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_INDEX1MSB`, `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_INDEX4LSB` and `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_INDEX4MSB`.

1/ When I create a surface from a bitmap with a depth of 4bpp or less, I expect the pixel format to be one of those:

```
SDL_Surface *surface = SDL_LoadBMP("test.bmp"); // bitmap with a 16-color palette
if(surface != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", SDL_GetPixelFormatName(surface->format->format));
}
else
{
    printf("%s\n", SDL_GetError());
}
```

But it outputs invariably:

> SDL_PIXELFORMAT_INDEX8

What is the reason?

2/ The other case is the creation of a surface from scratch:

```
Uint8 pixels[32] = {
    0xf0, 0x0f, 0xf0, 0x0f, // trying to put 2 pixels per byte
    0x0f, 0xf0, 0x0f, 0xf0,
    0xf0, 0x0f, 0xf0, 0x0f,
    0x0f, 0xf0, 0x0f, 0xf0,
    0xf0, 0x0f, 0xf0, 0x0f,
    0x0f, 0xf0, 0x0f, 0xf0,
    0xf0, 0x0f, 0xf0, 0x0f,
    0x0f, 0xf0, 0x0f, 0xf0
};

SDL_Surface *surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormatFrom(pixels, 8, 8, 4, 4, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_INDEX4LSB); // 8px width, 0.5 byte for 1 pixel, is the pitch 4?
if(surface != NULL)
{
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    if(texture != NULL)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
}
```

Output:

> Blit combination not supported

Surface creation seems OK, but I can't use it. Any attempt to create a texture from the surface, or convert the format (with [SDL_ConvertSurface](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_ConvertSurface) or [SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat)) gives the same error.

What is the point of these pixel formats and how can I use them?

Comment: Not supported, basically. And with renderer it makes no sense to support them, as your resulting texture would be RGB8, while surface is only temporary - so what's the point? Monochrome 8bit should be fine though, it is just pallettes that are a bit... no longer there.

Comment: I would like to hardcode the pixel values ​​of simple textures, and putting several pixels per byte seemed a little more efficient.

Comment: Indexed colours uses palette; is adding indirection really the natural way to simplify things? I have my doubts. But if I had that requirement I would have performed conversion to RGB8 manually at texture creation stage, then discard temporary surface.

Comment: Looks like a good solution, I'll try this approach.